# Errors running NPM commands after posting React app to github pages.

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages, package.json, npm-start

Everything was working before deploying to github pages, and the first deploy worked no problem. But ever since, now when running any NPM commands in the project, I'm getting this set of errors:

> geekcentric => npm start
>
> npm ERR! file /mnt/c/Users/GeekCentric/Documents/ReactJS/the_app/package.json
>
> npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token / in JSON at position 611 while >parsing near '...": "^1.2.0"
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse   }
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse }
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse // geekcentric => np...'
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just >JavaScript.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /home/geekcentric/.npm/_logs/2018-09-11T00_38_07_636Z->debug.log

The error is in my package.json file but I can't find anything that would throw the error or what's going wrong.

> {
>
> > "name": "the_app",
> >
> > "version": "0.1.0",
> >
> > "private": true,
> >
> > "homepage": "http://me.github.io/the_app", //added
> >
> > "dependencies": {
> >
> > > "axios": "^0.18.0",
> > >
> > > "firebase": "^5.4.2",
> > >
> > > "react": "^16.4.2",
> > >
> > > > "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
> > > >
> > > > "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
> > > >
> > > > ```
> > > > "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
> > > > ```
>
> },
>
> "scripts": {
>
> ```
> "start": "react-scripts start",
>
> "build": "react-scripts build",
>
> "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
>
> "eject": "react-scripts eject",
>
> "predeploy": "npm run build", //added
>
> "deploy": "gh-pages -d build" //added
> ```
>
> },
>
> "devDependencies": {
>       "gh-pages": "^1.2.0"
>     }
>   }

I'm using the create-react-app and the gh-pages npm module. 
Any help would be very appreciated, thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my text editor (VSCODE) and its working fine now. I use the built in terminal with WSL so I can only imagine I inadvertently screwed up a critical path. Still really curious to know what happened and why only after posting to gh-pages but the errors are gone and everything is running as you would expect.